# git checkout -b dev remote_repo/dev do not get all commits from remote

Tags: git, git-branch

This is my remote `dev` branch log:

```
[root@www admin_site]# git log -n4
commit 5852c812ddeb9b8611f1142de3d5048b99974011
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 17 16:39:46 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-17-wxc-02'

commit 99daaedb179979e71d9c8a302865980c9717073f
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 17 16:26:30 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-17-wxc-01'

commit a2b22ff9245f1ee82109d0ac3b003fd403d8d3b1
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 11 05:30:03 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-11-wxc-02'

commit 67584611401876ac4f51f306c9dbea2b9fd84ca9
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 11 05:18:14 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-11-wxc-01'
```

and in my local repo I create the branch base on the remote `dev` branch:

```
$ git checkout -b dev remote_repo/dev
```

But when I log it I only get two commits, there lost two commits:

```
$ git log -n4
commit a2b22ff9245f1ee82109d0ac3b003fd403d8d3b1 (HEAD -> dev, remote_repo/dev)
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 11 05:30:03 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-11-wxc-02'

commit 67584611401876ac4f51f306c9dbea2b9fd84ca9
Author: peter <429186dd7@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 11 05:18:14 2019 +0800

    '2019-09-11-wxc-01'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing a `git fetch` before you do the `git checkout -b dev remote_repo/dev`

As I understand it, git doesn't update its understanding of what the remote has until you do a `fetch` (or a `pull` which includes fetch).

So your `checkout -b` will set it to the state that the remote was at, last time you refreshed the information about the remote with a `fetch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You just base on the remote repo branch created a branch,

you should pull the remote branch, then you can get the latest commits.

```
git pull remote_repo dev
```